# How to read configuration from root of appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0

I want to have a simple *appsettings.json* for a console .NET 7 application with parameters in the root of the file.
Like this

```json
{
  "Key1": 1,
  "Key2": 2
}
```

How to read this in the application into a simple structure like this?

```
public struct Settings
{
   public required int Key1 { get; set; }
   public required int Key2 { get; set; }
}
```

I use a *host*, but what then?

```
var host = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder();
var config = host.Configuration.???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative for you:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration);

var app = builder.Build();
app.Run();
```

If you still want to use `Host.CreateApplicationBuilder()` should be similar:

```
var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder();

builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration);

var host = builder.Build();
host.Run();
```

Settings class:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public int Key1 { get; set; }
    public int Key2 { get; set; }
}
```

Settings file `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Key1": 1,
  "Key2": 2
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Just all the examples use a subsection in appsettings.json. No any example how to read the json root.